# Is this a Date Comparison bug or in one of my field?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, datetime, comparison

Good Day Every One

as i create queries for my project i stumbled upon this bug

when i use this code

```
DECLARE @MONTH VARCHAR(10)
SET @MONTH = 'MAY'
DECLARE @YEAR VARCHAR(4)
SET @YEAR= '2012'

    SELECT COUNT (*) AS CYJEWELRY
    FROM Transactions.tbl_PawnItem PIT
    INNER JOIN Transactions.tbl_PawnMain PMN
    ON PIT.fld_PawnMainID= PMN.fld_PawnMainID
    INNER JOIN Transactions.tbl_PawnHisto PHI
    ON PHI.fld_PawnMainID = PMN.fld_PawnMainID
    WHERE PMN.fld_StatusID = 3 /* OR PMN.fld_StatusID = 4*/ 
    AND DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,PHI.fld_LoanDate),0) =  DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,DATEADD (MONTH,-4,@MONTH+@YEAR)),0)
    AND PMN.fld_StorageGroupID  >= 3 and PMN.fld_StorageGroupID <= 14
```

**The results are CYJEWELRY = 23**

When i use the status ID 4 like this

```
DECLARE @MONTH VARCHAR(10)
SET @MONTH = 'MAY'
DECLARE @YEAR VARCHAR(4)
SET @YEAR= '2012'

    SELECT COUNT (*) AS CYJEWELRY
    FROM Transactions.tbl_PawnItem PIT
    INNER JOIN Transactions.tbl_PawnMain PMN
    ON PIT.fld_PawnMainID= PMN.fld_PawnMainID
    INNER JOIN Transactions.tbl_PawnHisto PHI
    ON PHI.fld_PawnMainID = PMN.fld_PawnMainID
    WHERE /*PMN.fld_StatusID = 3  OR */ PMN.fld_StatusID = 4
    AND DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,PHI.fld_LoanDate),0) =  DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,DATEADD (MONTH,-4,@MONTH+@YEAR)),0)
    AND PMN.fld_StorageGroupID  >= 3 and PMN.fld_StorageGroupID <= 14
```

**The results are CYJEWELRY = 34**

The question is why does when i use both of them like this

```
DECLARE @MONTH VARCHAR(10)
SET @MONTH = 'MAY'
DECLARE @YEAR VARCHAR(4)
SET @YEAR= '2012'

    SELECT COUNT (*) AS CYJEWELRY
    FROM Transactions.tbl_PawnItem PIT
    INNER JOIN Transactions.tbl_PawnMain PMN
    ON PIT.fld_PawnMainID= PMN.fld_PawnMainID
    INNER JOIN Transactions.tbl_PawnHisto PHI
    ON PHI.fld_PawnMainID = PMN.fld_PawnMainID
    WHERE PMN.fld_StatusID = 3  OR  PMN.fld_StatusID = 4
    AND DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,PHI.fld_LoanDate),0) =  DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,DATEADD (MONTH,-4,@MONTH+@YEAR)),0)
    AND PMN.fld_StorageGroupID  >= 3 and PMN.fld_StorageGroupID <= 14
```

**the results turn to be CYJEWELRY = 380?(i know this is wrong) instead of 57?**

any tips? or suggestions? to improve my code and remove the bug?? that would be higly appreciated by me im new in t-sql please be gentle :) thank you so much :)

Comment: Your month comparison will kill your performance, use PHI.fld_LoanDate >= startofmonth and PHI.fld_LoanDate < startofnextmonth (You need to calculate those parameters). This will fix your other problem: PMN.fld_StatusID in (3, 4)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk thanks for the tip! i know it will kill the performance of the system i wonder how would i calculate those parameters if the given input is Month varchar ex.(September), Year Varchar ex.(2013), especially if i need to subtract 4 months on the date given! :( can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yuo need to add brackets around the OR

Something like

```
WHERE (PMN.fld_StatusID = 3  OR  PMN.fld_StatusID = 4)
AND DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,PHI.fld_LoanDate),0) =  DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,DATEADD (MONTH,-4,@MONTH+@YEAR)),0)
AND PMN.fld_StorageGroupID  >= 3 and PMN.fld_StorageGroupID <= 14
```

When you look at the execution precedance

Writing

```
WHEN a = b 
OR   c = d
AND  e = f
```

this is the same as saying

```
WHEN a = b 
OR   (c = d AND  e = f)
```

whereas you intentions where

```
WHEN (a = b OR c = d)
AND  e = f
```

Have a look at [Logical Operator Precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186992%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> When more than one logical operator is used in a statement, NOT is
>   evaluated first, then AND, and finally OR. Arithmetic, and bitwise,
>   operators are handled before logical operators.

Also look at the table in [Operator Precedence (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)

Comment: ill accept this as an answer as soon as i can :) thank you so much sir can you please explain to me how those parenthesis affects the results of the code? thank you :)